# tkinter python switching widgets

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
root = Tk()
l = Label ( root , text = "bla" )
b = Button ( root , text = "python je glup" )

def glupsam ():
   b.grid_forget()
   b.update_idletasks()
   l.grid ( row = 0 , column = 0 )
   l.update_idletasks()
   sleep ( 2 )
   l.grid_forget()
   l.update_idletasks()
   b.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

b.grid( row = 0 , column = 0 )
b.configure ( command = glupsam )

root.mainloop()
```

Im new to python and tkinter.
Why this code doesnt switch label and button on grid (0, 0 ) everytime button is pressed , but only the first time

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but Tkinter doesn't play nicely with `sleep` - when you sleep, the window will simply freeze up until your function finishes executing. You may have to refactor your code to use `Tk.after` instead.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I didn't know that about sleep. It solved all my problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `after` to restore your button, instead of using `sleep`.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
root = Tk()
l = Label ( root , text = "bla" )
b = Button ( root , text = "python je glup" )

def glupsam ():
    b.grid_forget()
    b.update_idletasks()
    l.grid ( row = 0 , column = 0 )
    l.update_idletasks()
    def f():
        l.grid_forget()
        l.update_idletasks()
        b.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
    root.after(2000, f)

b.grid( row = 0 , column = 0 )
b.configure ( command = glupsam )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need the call to `update_idletasks` anywhere in your solution.